# Inherit multiple querysets in Django?

Tags: django, multiple-inheritance, django-queryset

Is it acceptable to inherit multiple `QuerySet` classes ?

Simple question, but didn't find much info on google.. :(

I'd like to *inherit django-model-utils*'s `InheritanceQuerySet` and my custom mixins(which subclassed *django*'s `model.QuerySet`)

-- EDIT --

Suppose *InheritanceQuerySet* has `_clone()` method.
Down the road, I may need to inherit *OtherQuerySet* which also has `_clone()` method.

`_clone()` copies something specific to the class and calls `super._clone()`

I worried if first *_clone()* would hide the second *_clone()* in `MRO` and affect the functionality.

(But I guess since `_clone()` calls the `super`, I don't need to worry about 'hiding', writing out sometimes solves the problem.)

Then, I was worried because 'queryset multiple inheritance' doesn't yield many google results although I think it's really good way to add functionality to manager.

(I'm thinking to make a queryset which inherits multiple queryset related *mixin* which has object as base, or *models.QuerySet* as base.
Then I can use `PassThroughManager` or alike(from_queryset from django 1.7) to use the all-the-powerful queryset)

Comment: You clearly know that multiple inheritance is fine in Python, since you're asking about mixins - do you have specific areas of concern? I haven't worked with the `InheritanceQuerySet` class you mention, so I hesitate to blithely say it'll all work fine, but I don't think any of the Django magic will make it more complicated than your average multiple inheritance situation.